# Unable to reach expo servers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, rxjs

Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo" installed in your project.

Comment: i run my react native project using "npm start" above error will occurs , solution will be apreciated

Answer (score 9):

Instead of writing npm start use expo start

Comment: please write sample code

Comment: `expo start` is the exact command

Answer (score 7):

This could be a network error. Try running the project with the offline flag: `npx expo start --offline`

Answer (score 1):

Just do a cleanup and rebuild your modules
Follow the below steps:

```
delete node_modules .expo .vscode
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npx expo install
npx expo start --clear
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using expo cli -g 46 above
run:
npx expo start

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and flushing DNS cache worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When facing the problem of being unable to reach expo server, try to solve it using the following command: '`expo r -c`'

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same below error

Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo" installed in your project

Inside the root directory of the project

Run following command `

> `npx expo start --clear`

`

Answer (score -5):

Please consider this, and/or clarify the question.

Creating an expo app:

```
npx create-expo-app my-app
```

Navigating into project folder:

```
cd my-app
```

Launching an expo application:

```
expo start
```